# If I create a menu in Bash is command style history possible

Tags: linux, bash, shell, menu

I have no problem creating the menu - that is not what this question is about.

What happens however is I go from having the arrow keys be useful (scroll up and down to get access to previous commands I've run at the command line) to completely useless (`^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D^[[C`)

Is there any way to encapsulate that behaviour into a menu?

E.g. can I use the scroll up and down keys to access previous options I've selected. (It's a BIG menu and I have MANY options like `dev.client.alpha` or `dev.otherclient.beta` etc...)

I supposed I could break each one into separate files and just use the command line diredtly OR I could pass an augment to the menu so as to call: `~/menu dev.clint.alpha` directly from the command line.

Just curious is anyone else has (had) this itch and if anything has ever been done about it?

Menu I'm presently using is done basically as follows:

```
while :
   clear
   do
    echo "$MENU"
    read CHOICE ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ARG4 overflow
    case $CHOICE in
        command.a)
            # do stuff here
            ;;
        command.b)
            # do different stuff here
            ;;
        *) # catch all...
            continue 
            ;;
        esac
    done
clear
```

Comment: Please add some source code to your question. A menu could be implemented many ways.

Comment: Source code added as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want by enabling **readline** on your read,
and appending each choice reply to the internal history. You can even save
the history to a file so when you rerun the script you have the old
history. For example:

```
HISTFILE=/tmp/myhistory
history -r # read old history
while :
do  echo "MENU. a b q"
    read -e # sets REPLY, enables readline
    history -s "$REPLY" # add to history
    history -w # save to file
    set -- $REPLY
    CHOICE=$1; shift
    ARG1=$1 ARG2=$2 ARG3=$3 ARG4=$4; shift 4
    overflow="$*"
    case $CHOICE in
        a) echo do stuff here $ARG1 ;;
        b) echo do different stuff here ;;
        q) exit ;;
        *) echo catch all...
            continue ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I'm going to check that out - thanks! It's worth nothing that multi-line statements can go for each option -- just end each line with `;` and each command set with `;;`  and also note that options do not have to be simple letters.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. `ARG1=$1 ARG2=$1 ARG3=$1 ARG4=$4; shift 4` should be `ARG1=$1 ARG2=$2 ARG3=$3 ARG4=$4; shift 4` no?